# How to design a struct for different size of arrays using strings?

Tags: arrays, matlab, struct

I have different size of arrays such as `[6:8]`, `[11:21]`, `[14:15]`, etc.
I need to assign these values to a variable set which should contain strings specified in a different array. Let me give an example:

```
variables = ["a", "b", "c"];

% I need to design a structure just like below but inside a for loop. 
% Because I've lots of variables and arrays.
xx.a = [6:8];
xx.b = [11:21];
xx.c = [14:15];
```

Is there any solution proposal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how your data is organized, but you can use the strings of your `variables` array to index the struct fields dynamically:

```
variables = ["a", "b", "c"];
data{1} = [6:8];
data{2} = [11:21];
data{3} = [14:15];

% Use string indexing of structs within loop
for ii = 1:numel(variables)
    xx.(variables(ii)) = data{ii};
end
```

---

```
xx = 

  struct with fields:

    a: [6 7 8]
    b: [11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21]
    c: [14 15]
```

Comment: Yes. That's what I'm looking for. Thanks a lot